# What it means if calling "Open Call Hierarchy" in Eclipse returns only the method on which the check was run?

Tags: java, methods, call, hierarchy

I am calling "Open Call Hierarchy" on a someMethod() in a java application source code. In the results window I can see only someMethod() and no any other methods.

The settings for "Open Call Hierarchy" are set as follows:
Field Access: All references
Search in: Sources, Required Projects, JRE Libraries and Application libraries
Search scope: Workspace
Max call depth: 99 (nothing else set ing filters)

With these options I would assume that my scope is set to everything (all code) checked out in my Eclipse Workspace.

Would it be safe to assume that since no caller method was found, the someMethod() is not used by the application?

If not, could you help me to undederstand what else could invoke this method? How would I know if anything uses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be invocations via reflection and from native methods which are not searched by "Open Call Hierarchy" command.

Answer (score 0):

When I encounter such a problem, I usually simply use the Eclipse-function Search->File... to search a method through all related files in the workspace. That would also cover those reflection-cases and native usages unless the methodname is determined by iteration or other dynamic construction.